# pointer to functions?

Tags: c++, pointers

say I have

```
class B{   //base class

}

class A : public B{ //derived class
}
```

I also have a function that returns a pointer to class B

```
B* returnB(){
    B * object = new A; //pointer of base class allocate object of derived class
    return object;
}
```

now when i try to make a pointer to function B*, I get an error

```
B* (*randomFunction)();
randomFunction = returnB;
```

Visual Studios wont compile.

```
1   IntelliSense: a value of type "B*(MediaFactory::*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "B*(*)()" c:\Users\...\mediafactory.cpp   35
```

Comment: Member function pointers are different than free function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to assign a pointer to a member function of class `MediaFactory` into a variable that can hold a non-member function. These entities aren't compatible. Either use boost `bind` or change your function pointer variable to be of `B* (MediaFactory::*)()` type.

Comment: `std::bind` is an option, too!

Comment: when you say B* (MediaFactory::*)()  . Do I give it a name like B* (MediaFactory::*randomName)()

Comment: Yes, just add the class name scope:`B* (MediaFactory::*funcName)() = &MediaFactory::funcNameInMediaFactory`

Comment: when I try to call `funcName()` i get  `3 IntelliSense: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type c:\...\mediafactory.cpp 54`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a pointer-to-member function to a function pointer.

A method of your class, unless static, has a different signature and approach to calling. The simple function declaration does not account for class representations (e.g. implicit `this`).

See here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html